# Using the mapping cone to show that a chain map defines a stable equivalence between two symmetric algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, modular-representation-theory

This question is about an argument in the proof of Theorem 9.8.8 in Linckelmanns Block Theory of Finite Group Algebras. I need to understand the argument in order to do something similar in my research.

Let $A$ and $B$ be symmetric algebras and $C$ a complex of $(A,B)$-bimodules. Then $C$ is a stable equivalence if there is are isomorphisms of chain complexes $C\otimes_B C^* \cong A \oplus Z$ and $C^*\otimes_B C \cong B \oplus Z'$ where $Z$ is homotopy equivalent to a complex of projective $(A,A)$-bimodules and $Z'$ is homotopy equivalent to a complex of projective $(B,B)$-bimodules.

If $C$ is a complex of modules which areprojective as left modules and as right modules, then the functors $C\otimes_B -$ and $C^*\otimes_A-$ are biadjoint and thus there are several natural chain maps $A\to C\otimes_B C^* \to A$ and $B\to C^*\otimes_A C \to B$ coming from the units/counits of the adjunctions. The idea is that one can use these maps to show that $A$ and $B$ are stable equivalent.

In Theorem 9.8.8, the author is trying to show that a complex $C$ defines a stable equivalance. In order to do it, he simply shows that the cone of the map $B\to C^*\otimes_A C$ is homotopy equivalent to a complex of projectives and then concludes the proof without further comment.

How does one obtain a chain isomorphism $C^*\otimes_A C \cong B\oplus Z'$ using this property of the cone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give three answers, which basically say: (A) it doesn't matter,
(B) it's not true, and (C) here's (a sketch of) a proof.

But before that, there are a couple of relevant conditions in Linckelmann's
theorem that are not stated in the question. First, the algebras $A$ and $B$ are
indecomposable $\mathcal{O}$-free $\mathcal{O}$-algebras for a discrete valuation ring $\mathcal{O}$. Second, the complex $C$ is
bounded.

(A) I think that Linckelmann uses the definition of ``induces a stable
equivalence'' given  in the question in order to avoid getting too immersed in
technicalities of triangulated categories.

What's really going on is that the stable module category is the Verdier
quotient of the bounded derived category of finitely generated modules by the
subcategory of perfect complexes (i.e., the complexes that are quasi-isomorphic
to bounded complexes of projective modules).

If $Z'$ is a bounded complex of projective bimodules then $Z'\otimes_{B}X$ is a
perfect complex of (left) $A$-modules for any bounded complex $X$ of finitely
generated $\mathcal{O}$-free $B$-modules. So if the unit map $B\to C^{\ast}\otimes_{A}C$ is an
isomorphism modulo bounded complexes of projective bimodules (in particular, if
the mapping cone of the unit map is a bounded complex of projective bimodules),
then tensoring with $C^{\ast}\otimes_{A}C$ is isomorphic to the identity functor
on the stable module category.

So the condition on the mapping cone is sufficient to get a stable equivalence.

(B) The theorem states that, in a certain situation involving blocks with defect
group $P$, $C$ inducing a stable equivalence (defined as in the question) is
equivalent to some other conditions.

But if the defect group $P$ is trivial, then the zero complex $C$ vacuously
satisfies the other conditions, but it is certainly not true that there is any
$Z'$ such that $C^{\ast}\otimes_{A}C\cong B\oplus Z'$.

(C) The functors $C\otimes_{B}-$ and $C^{\ast}\otimes_{B}-$ are biadjoint not
just at the level of complexes, but at the level of the stable module
category. If the unit $B\to C^{\ast}\otimes_{A}C$ is an isomorphism in the
stable module category of bimodules (and similarly for the other units/counits)
then the composition
$$B\to C^{\ast}\otimes_{A}C\to B$$
is a stable isomorphism, which implies, if $B$ has no summands that are
projective bimodules (which is the case if $B$ is an indecomposable algebra that
is not projective as a $B$-$B$-bimodule), that it is an isomorphism of
bimodules. So the unit map
$B\to C^{\ast}\otimes_{A}C$ is a split monomorphism of complexes of bimodules.

Comment: (A) I think I follow this. In either scenario, $C$ defines an equivalence between the stable module categories. Follow up question: is it a triangulated equivalence?

(B) I think you saying that the theorem is false as stated, is that right? However, in the example, $C$ still defines an equivalence between the stable module categories since every module belonging to those blocks is projective.

(C) How do you view the functor $C\otimes_B-$ on the stable module category? In this scenario, does the condition on the cone of the unit map force the cokernel to be a complex of projectives?

Comment: @jb2g4 (A) Yes, it’s a triangulated equivalence. (B) Exactly. (C) $C\otimes_B-$ defines a functor between bounded derived categories that restricts to an functor between the subcategories consisting of perfect complexes, and therefore induces a functor between the quotient categories: i.e., between the stable module categories. I’m not sure what cokernel you’re asking about.

Comment: The cokernel of the unit map $B \to C^*\otimes_A C$. You explained why it will be a split monomorphism if $B$ is indecomposable and non-projective (I think that rules out the example where $B$ is a block with defect 0). If it had a cokernel which was a complex of projective modules, that would give the desired isomorphism $C^*\otimes_A C^* \cong B\oplus Z'$.

Comment: @jb2g4 The cokernel of a split monomorphism is homotopy equivalent to the mapping cone, so yes, if the mapping cone is homotopy equivalent to a complex of projectives, then so will the cokernel.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Is there a good reference for results like that?

Comment: @jb2g4 The fact I mentioned is quite easy (just consider what the mapping cone of a split monomorphism of complexes looks like). A more general useful fact is that if $X\to Y$ is a map of complexes that is a split monomorphism *in each degree* (much weaker than being a split monomorphism of complexes), then the mapping cone is homotopy equivalent to the cokernel. I’m sure this fact can be found in many sources, but it is Exercise 11.8 in Kashiwara & Schapira’s *Categories and Sheaves*, for example (with hints).